# Scraping a wikipedia table with Rvest (error)

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, rvest, wikipedia

I am trying to scrape a table on this wikipedia page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_Parliament_constituencies

Specifically, the table under the section "England". This is my code:

```
install.packages("rvest")
library("rvest")
install.packages("xml2")
library("xml2")
install.packages("magrittr")
library("magrittr")

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_Parliament_constituencies"

read_html(url)

list <- url %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[2]') %>%
  `html_table()

list<- list[[1]]
```

However, I'm getting these two errors:

```
list <- url %>%
+   html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[2]') %>%
+   html_table()
```

Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"

```
list<- list[[1]]
```

Error in list[[1]] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first error is because you are trying to apply a method for `read_html` (`html_nodes`) directly to the url. You need to place the `read_html(url)` in the chain of commands:

```
items <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[2]') %>% html_table()
```

For your second error (and related to my renaming of your variable above); list is an in-built method so shouldn't be used as a variable name. Rename that variable where ever used:

```
items <- items[[1]]
```

I would probably re-write to use faster css class selector and `html_node` method to retrieve only the one table. Then use a more descriptive name.

```
constituency_table <- read_html(url) %>% html_node('.wikitable') %>% html_table()
```